# Golang and AngularJS template conflict

Tags: angularjs, go

I have a conflict with golang html/template and angularjs delimiters. I know that there is a method that lets to change delimiter in Go, but it does not work for me. Maybe it should be called before parsing of files? Could you please provide an example, how it should be implemented.

I found a lot of comments that AngularJS and Go should not have any conflict because they should be used separately. As I understand, Go should be used only for backend (REST). The question is, how AngularJS, HTML should be loaded? In this case, should I have to servers?

Comment: It isn't a perfect solution, but one option is to avoid raw angular template delimiters in your golang templates by using ng-bind instead of template delimiters, like this: ```<span ng-bind="var"></span>```. Most of your templates files can be included by json request and not parsed as golang templates, so the annoying of having to use ng-bind can be limited.

Comment: if you like to change the delims from AngularJS, i use $interpolateProvider this way: http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2015/03/golang-template-with-angularjs.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea behind AngularJS is to have all the rendering process run on the client side.

If you follow this logic all along, you do not need any rendering on the server side (e.g : no call to `template.Execute`) when serving AngularJS html files, you simply have to serve static content.

Comment: This answer basically says that you shouldn't mix templates which doesn't answer the question about how to mix templates. It is true that in most cases, you don't need to mix the templates, but that's not always the case (for instance, you might be using feature flags that are conditionals on your base template). The question author, knows that Delims() needs to be used but couldn't get it work properly.

Answer (score 32):

you need to change the delimiters characters used that's all. I've had the same problem before on Beego because of the exact templating characters `{{ }}` and once I changed that to `<<<>>>` I managed to serve the html without any problems.

You basically need to call this function before you do any parsing: `func (t *Template) Delims(left, right string) *Template`

for more details:

> http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Delims

Comment: Those who using beego [use this link](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md#template-tags)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

```
indexTmpl = template.New("index.html").Delims("<<", ">>")
indexTmpl, _ = indexTmpl.ParseFiles("index.html")
```

Answer (score 8):

**Solution that won't require changing delimiters:**

Use `{{"{{"}}` for opening and `{{"}}"}}` for closing angular expressions.

**Example**:

```
{{"{{"}} 1 + 2 {{"}}"}}
```

Comment: I tried changing the delims, but it gave errors. Because I guess the app engine's go version is 1.4 while go version is 1.5 and there likely is a bug with the old 1.4 version. finally your hack worked.

Comment: but it doesn't work with angular2, where I have to use typescript converter.

Comment: This is the only thing works after hours of digging Google

Answer (score 5):

Here is a full example of using [Golang HTML templates + Angular.js](https://github.com/mattetti/goHtmlTemplateExample) by setting delimiters as mentioned by others. The reason for this example is that it shows an end to end experience, setting up the serving of static assets, template parsing and of course angular.js integration.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Bijans answer but a bit more readable. You can use "printf" in your template to print a string literal. This works just the same for the  "html/template" package.

---

For example: `{{ printf "{{}}"}}`. https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview

Answer (score 1):

As Yasir said, you should change delimiters. I martini with [[ and ]] delimiters and it works with no problems.