# Use {{}} raw expressions in a Go template

Tags: go, beego

I'm trying to render `{{ verb }}` as raw html in a Go template.  However, I can't find a way to escape this so Go doesn't try to interpret it.

So far, I've come up with

```
{{print "{{ verb }}"}}
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459706/golang-and-angularjs-template-conflict/20459787#20459787

Comment: I'm using beego for rendering, so changing the delimiter doesn't appear to be an option.

Comment: actually you can do that with beego using `beego.TemplateLeft = <<<` and `beego.TemplateRight = >>>`

Answer (score 0):

somethimes ? You  can try it :

```
verb :="{{"+verb+"}}"
{{print .verb }}
```

All verb ?

the best way :    change the template tag "{{}}" to other