# AnguarJS expression error on goland

Tags: angularjs, goland

I am developing an AngularJS application on [Goland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/).

Goland claims error on an expression `{{ count * times }}` as below.

[image]

I am enabling AngularJS plugin on Goland as below.

[image]

Why `{{count * times}}` got error on Goland? How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround open `Help | Edit Custom Properties` and add `go.disable.template.substitution=true` there. Then restart the IDE.

Also, it makes sense to vote for and follow to the corresponding [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/GO-4846).

Answer (score 1):

Go uses `{{` and `}}` as the default template tags. In the case that these tags conflict with other template tags as in AngularJS, we can use other tags.

```
indexTmpl = template.New("index.html").Delims("<<", ">>")
indexTmpl, _ = indexTmpl.ParseFiles("index.html")
```

**For more Info:** [Golang and AngularJS template conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459706/golang-and-angularjs-template-conflict)

Comment: I understand Go and AngularJS template is conflicting. Can you let me know how I can disable this error message on Goland IDE?